# How to declare a temporary table in sybase function and update the same

Tags: function, sybase

```
CREATE FUNCTION TagList(@ticketNr varchar)
RETURNS varchar(500)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @list varchar(500)
    SELECT tag INTO #Temp from TicketTag where ticket=ticketNr
    DECLARE @res_csv  VARCHAR(500)
    update #Temp SET @res_csv = COALESCE(@res_csv+', ','') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, tag)
    RETURN @res_csv
END;
```

And iam receiving error Illegal SELECT statement within a scalar SQL function.
Illegal UPDATE statement within a scalar SQL function.

Comment: You can't create tables inside of a scalar function in Sybase.

Comment: How can i make the logic work in that case? i need multiple rows in a single row and this logic works fine when executed normally without function. But i need to run it as a dynamic one for list of input.

Comment: You could create it as a stored procedure instead perhaps? If you think logically about it a scalar function is often for use in select statements usually and creating a table or updating a table has the need for implicit transactions, which is why you can't do it in a function.

Comment: Intention was to use this function in a stored procedure, ok, will try to add it to existing stored procedure